# Selecting a record because its date field is X days after another records date field SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, window-functions, unpivot

I have a table, GameData, with columns; GameID, Date, StartTime, Duration, AteamId, HteamID, Ascore, Hscore, Attendance in my nba db. It basically holds data on NBA games. I want to select all the records for a specific team that are played after X days of rest.

I am having trouble selecting the records so far I have
`select * from GameData where Date+2 in (Select Date from GameData) and ATeamID = 1030;` But this just gets all the records with Date values that are two days apart for a specific team, but it doesn't check if there a records in between. It should only be selecting games that are 2 days after the last played, not games that are simply 2 days after a game regardless if there are games played in between.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot the table with `union all` to generate one row per game and team, then use `lag()` to get the date of the "previous" game, and finally use that information to filter:

```
select gd.*
from (
    select gd.*, lag(date) over(partition by team order by date) lag_date 
    from (
        select gd.*, ateam team from gamedata gd
        union all
        select gd.*, hteam team from gamedata gd
    ) gd
) gd
where date > lag_date + interval 2 day
```

Comment: Im getting an Error 1064 (42000) near '(partition by team order by date) lag_date from ( select gd.*, ATeamID team from'    is 'date' refering to the date or my field titled 'Date' and should ateam, and hteam be ATeamID and HTeamID. Also what does team signify, is it a temp var or refering to TeamID which is what makes up the ATeamID and HTeamID. Thank you for commenting

Comment: @ThomasBrianTierneyIII: this query requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, what you ask for will be more challenging to achieve.

Comment: Ok I updated my mysql version to 8 and it kind of works now. The lag_date isn't hardly ever 2 days before the selected record, but I notice you state what I want is more challenging. I was thinking of exporting some of my tables as csv files and then try creating an R or python func to help do what I want, but I felt that it was defeating the whole point of why I made the sql db. What do you think @GMB

Comment: @ThomasBrianTierneyIII: I don't know what you mean. If you are running MySQL 8.0, this query should work and produce the result that you want. If the results are not as desired, would you please provide a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with sample data and an explanation of what is not working as intended?

Comment: After updating it your code ran with no errors. However say a team plays a game on the first, then rests for the 2nd day, then plays a game on the 3rd and another on the 4th. I want it to not count this occurrence because the team didn’t have 2 rest days, but it does now because it doesn’t check to see if a game is played in between